# How to list S3 objects efficiently?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-glue

I have implemented a pipeline where I only want to list the objects modified or added after a specific time. I have written the below code and that is working fine but it is not that efficient. My source contains continuous CDC Data that is large in number (999+).

As per my understanding, the below code will list objects based on the prefix first and later it filters out objects last modified at or after the specified date/time. Can we skip listing all the objects every time?

The time taken by the code for the timestamp `2010-07-25 00:00:00+00:00` is the same as the time taken for `2023-07-25 00:00:00+00:00`. Ideally, for the 2023 datetime, it should take less time because the total number of objects with the first timestamp `2010-07-25 00:00:00+00:00` is around 1M but with `2023-07-25 00:00:00+00:00` it is only 4 objects.

```
import json, boto3

def get_objects(bucket, key):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    s3_paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    s3_iterator = s3_paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=key)
    print(s3_iterator)
    filtered_iterator = s3_iterator.search(
        "Contents[?to_string(LastModified)>='\"2023-07-25 00:00:00+00:00\"'].Key"
    )
    c = 0
    for key_data in filtered_iterator:
        c =  c + 1
        print(str(c) + '--> ' + str(key_data))
        
    
    print("count is " + str(c))
```

Simply I want to implement the backend logic of the Glue Job Bookmark.

Comment: *"Can we skip listing all the objects every time?"* - no. Not if you want to support modifications of old files *and* your files are not place in a structure like `bucket/year/month/day/key-here.extension`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing objects in a large Amazon S3 bucket is quite time-consuming since each API call returns a maximum of 1000 objects.

Some alternatives are:

- Trigger an **AWS Lambda function** whenever objects are created. Write some code that either operates on the object immediately or writes the object information to a database so that it can be accessed quickly in future. *OR*
- Use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects. This way, you don't need to make *any* API calls but the list is only updated daily/weekly.

Comment: Do you know how the Glue Job bookmark works with S3? How it track?